# __rlshift__, __ror__ in Python

Tags: python, operators

I noticed that this [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122/#) seems to use `__rlshift__`, `__ror__` like operators. But, they aren't in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/operator.html)! Can anyone explain these and perhaps point to some docs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the documentation for:

- [`object.__rlshift__()`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=rlshift#object.__rlshift__)
- [`object.__ror__()`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=ror#object.__ror__)

`__rlshift__` is the swapped operands version of `__lshift__`, used when the right-hand operand supports the operation but the left-hand operand doesn't.

Comment: This is still confusing.  The documentation linked is too abstract. Could you give an example?